# UDP socket won't timeout

Tags: ruby

I've this sniped that won't work as I want it to.

```
def send(data)
  socket = UDPSocket.open

  Timeout::timeout(1.2) {
    socket.send(data, 0, host, port)
    resp = if select([socket], nil, nil, 3)
      socket.recvfrom_nonblock(65536)
    end
  }
end
```

If the server (host) is to slow or doesn't exists the example above will lock the current script.
It won't timeout. Any idea why?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2

It works as aspected when the server (host) exists.

Comment: FWIW, this works in ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout block worked, it was the code that called `#send` that was the problem.